# What do I need to run a program that uses Roslyn API?

Tags: c#, roslyn, .net-core

I'm a newbie to Roslyn compiler services, I would like to create an .exe with .net full or .net core which can call Roslyn API, that program must run on a machine that does not have installed Visual Studio, I just want to distribute (copy/paste) the .exe and it should work.

I have no idea what programs must be installed on that machine to my .exe can work properly (making calls to Roslyn API).

Can it run only with .net framework installed?

Comment: Try it and see (hint: you don't need anything besides what's in the NuGet package)

Answer (score 1):

Most of Roslyn is just a library, so if you build a project that references the Roslyn NuGet packages, it will compile into a directory of files that are all you need to run the application (assuming you have the appropriate version of .Net Framework or .Net Core installed).

If you really want just a single EXE file, you will need a tool that combines an application and its dependencies into a single file, like ILMerge.